# Polymer app-localstorage not working for session storage

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In polymer documentation its given that when we use app-localstorage and if we set property sessionOnly ="true" and storage="window.sessionStorage" data should store in session storage,but its still storing data in localstorage

```
 <paper-input value="{{myData}}"></paper-input>
<app-localstorage-document key="search" data="{{myData}}" sessionOnly="true" storage="window.sessionStorage">
</app-localstorage-document>
```

how to store data in session and its should destroy when user close the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your snippet of code.

*Firstly*, Polymer uses two kinds of cases - `camelCase` and `dash-case`. The first one is used for property names and the second one for attributes ([see specification](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#property-name-mapping)). And since you are using the `sessionOnly` property as an attribute, you should change it to `session-only`.

The corrected snippet of code is therefore:

```
<paper-input value="{{myData}}"></paper-input>
  <app-localstorage-document key="search" data="{{myData}}" session-only="true">
</app-localstorage-document>
```

*Secondly*, notice that I have also removed the `storage` attribute from my snippet of code. This property is computed and therefore cannot be set. This actually isn't clearly visible from the [element's API docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-storage/app-localstorage-document#property-storage), but only via inspecting the [element's source code](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-storage/blob/master/app-localstorage/app-localstorage-document.html):

```
storage: {
  type: Object,
  computed: '__computeStorage(sessionOnly)'
}
```

If you have any additional questions, don't hesitate to ask below in the comments.